Custom Mending Enchantment plugin 1.8.8 not applying
This is my first time creating a plugin, and I wanted to create a plugin for 1.8.8 that adds mending using /mending.
The problem I have is that when I do /mending on, for example, a diamond sword, it gets enchanted with the glowing effect and an nbt tag but not my Mending enchant. It also does not fix durability when I get XP.
If someone can help me, I would really appreciate it.
I got 4 classes
Main class (Mending 2)
package me.marmosat.mending2;

import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerExpChangeEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Mending2 extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    public static final CustomMendingEnchantment mendingEnchant = new CustomMendingEnchantment(240);

    @Override
    public void onLoad() {
        // Register the custom Mending enchantment
        CustomMendingEnchantment.registerEnchantment(this.getLogger());
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Register events
        getLogger().info("Mending2 plugin has been enabled!");
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);

        // Register the /mending command
        getCommand("mending").setExecutor(new MendingCommandExecutor(getLogger()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerExpChange(PlayerExpChangeEvent event) {
        // Check if player has Mending enchanted items
        for (ItemStack item : event.getPlayer().getInventory().getContents()) {
            if (item != null && item.containsEnchantment(CustomMendingEnchantment.getCustomMendingEnchantment())) {
                // Calculate repair cost based on damage
                int repairCost = calculateRepairCost(item);

                // Deduct repair cost from player's experience
                if (event.getAmount() >= repairCost) {
                    event.setAmount(event.getAmount() - repairCost);

                    // Repair the item
                    repairItem(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int calculateRepairCost(ItemStack item) {
        // Calculate repair cost based on damage
        int maxDurability = item.getType().getMaxDurability();
        int durability = maxDurability - item.getDurability();
        double repairCostPercentage = 0.2; // Example: 20% repair cost per durability point
        return (int) Math.ceil(durability * repairCostPercentage);
    }

    private void repairItem(ItemStack item) {
        // Repair the item by setting its durability to its maximum
        item.setDurability((short) 0);
    }
}

CustomMendingEnchantment
package me.marmosat.mending2;

import org.bukkit.enchantments.Enchantment;
import org.bukkit.enchantments.EnchantmentTarget;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class CustomMendingEnchantment extends Enchantment {

    private static boolean registered = false;
    private static Logger logger;
    private static CustomMendingEnchantment instance;

    // Constructor
    public CustomMendingEnchantment(int id) {
        super(id);
    }

    // Static method to register the custom enchantment
    public static void registerEnchantment(Logger pluginLogger) {
        logger = pluginLogger;
        instance = new CustomMendingEnchantment(240);
        try {
            Field acceptingNewField = Enchantment.class.getDeclaredField("acceptingNew");
            acceptingNewField.setAccessible(true);
            acceptingNewField.set(null, true); // Allow registering new enchantments

            Enchantment.registerEnchantment(instance);
            logger.info("Custom Mending enchantment registered!");
            registered = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            // Failed to register the enchantment
            logger.severe("Failed to register custom Mending enchantment!");
        }
    }

    // Static method to get the custom enchantment instance
    public static CustomMendingEnchantment getCustomMendingEnchantment() {
        if (instance == null) {
            // If the enchantment is not registered, return null
            logger.warning("Custom Mending enchantment has not been registered!");
        }
        return instance;
    }
    // Method to check if the enchantment is registered
    public static boolean isRegistered() {
        return registered;
    }

    // Implementing abstract method getName() from Enchantment
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Mending"; // Set the name of the enchantment
    }

    // Implementing abstract method getMaxLevel() from Enchantment
    @Override
    public int getMaxLevel() {
        return 1; // Set the maximum level of the enchantment
    }

    // Implementing abstract method getStartLevel() from Enchantment
    @Override
    public int getStartLevel() {
        return 1; // Set the starting level of the enchantment
    }

    // Implementing abstract method getItemTarget() from Enchantment
    @Override
    public EnchantmentTarget getItemTarget() {
        return EnchantmentTarget.BREAKABLE; // Specify the item target for the enchantment
    }

    // Implementing abstract method isTreasure() from Enchantment
    @Override
    public boolean isTreasure() {
        return false; // Indicate whether the enchantment is considered a treasure enchantment
    }

    // Implementing abstract method isCursed() from Enchantment
    @Override
    public boolean isCursed() {
        return false; // Indicate whether the enchantment is considered a curse
    }

    // Implementing abstract method conflictsWith(Enchantment) from Enchantment
    @Override
    public boolean conflictsWith(Enchantment other) {
        // Indicate whether this enchantment conflicts with another enchantment
        return false; // Mending does not conflict with other enchantments
    }

    // Implementing abstract method canEnchantItem(ItemStack) from Enchantment
    @Override
    public boolean canEnchantItem(ItemStack item) {
        // Return true if the item can be enchanted with this enchantment
        return true; // Can enchant any item
    }

    // Implementing other Enchantment methods as needed
}

MendingCommandExecutor
package me.marmosat.mending2;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MendingCommandExecutor implements CommandExecutor {

    private final Logger logger;

    // Constructor with Logger parameter
    public MendingCommandExecutor(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        // Check if the sender is a player
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("This command can only be executed by players.");
            return false;
        }

        Player player = (Player) sender;

        // Check if the player has permission to use the command
        if (!player.isOp()) {
            sender.sendMessage("You do not have permission to use this command.");
            return false;
        }

        try {
            // Get the item the player is currently holding in the main hand
            ItemStack heldItem = player.getInventory().getItemInHand(); // Deprecated in newer versions, but still usable in 1.8.8

            // Check if the held item is not air
            if (heldItem != null && heldItem.getType() != Material.AIR) {
                // Apply the Mending enchantment to the held item
                if (CustomMendingEnchantment.isRegistered()) {
                    heldItem.addUnsafeEnchantment(CustomMendingEnchantment.getCustomMendingEnchantment(), 1);
                    player.sendMessage("The item in your hand now has the Mending enchantment.");
                } else {
                    player.sendMessage("An error occurred while executing the command.");
                    logger.severe("Custom Mending enchantment is not registered.");
                }
            } else {
                player.sendMessage("You are not holding any item.");
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle any exceptions
            sender.sendMessage("An error occurred while executing the command.");
            logger.severe("Error while executing /mending command: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}

MendingListener
package me.marmosat.mending2;

import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerExpChangeEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

public class MendingListener implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerExpChange(PlayerExpChangeEvent event) {
        // Check if player has Mending enchanted items
        for (ItemStack item : event.getPlayer().getInventory().getContents()) {
            if (item != null && item.containsEnchantment(CustomMendingEnchantment.getCustomMendingEnchantment())) {
                // Calculate repair cost based on damage
                int repairCost = calculateRepairCost(item);
    
                // Deduct repair cost from player's experience
                if (event.getAmount() >= repairCost) {
                    event.setAmount(event.getAmount() - repairCost);
    
                    // Repair the item
                    repairItem(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private int calculateRepairCost(ItemStack item) {
        // Calculate repair cost based on damage
        int maxDurability = item.getType().getMaxDurability();
        int durability = maxDurability - item.getDurability();
        double repairCostPercentage = 0.2; // Example: 20% repair cost per durability point
        return (int) Math.ceil(durability * repairCostPercentage);
    }
    
    private void repairItem(ItemStack item) {
        // Repair the item by setting its durability to its maximum
        item.setDurability((short) 0);
    }

}


I'm not sure why the item is not showing the Mending enchant, but I think the durability issue is coming from a logic error within your code. In your onPlayerExpChange listener, you have the line:
if (event.getAmount() >= repairCost)

to (presumably) check and see if the player has enough experience to repair the item. However, event.getAmount() only returns the amount of exp the player will receive from the PlayerExpChangeEvent.
Unless you intended your code to run this way, the item's durability will only be fixed if that single exp change amount is greater than the exp needed to fix the item. If you want to fix the durability based on the player's total amount of experience, you need to get the player's total amount of experience and use that in your conditional instead of the exp amount from the event.
Here is an updated code snippet for the aforementioned event handler.
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerExpChange(PlayerExpChangeEvent event) {
    // Get target player from event
    Player player = event.getPlayer();

    // Check if player has Mending enchanted items
    for (ItemStack item : player.getInventory().getContents()) {
        if (item != null && item.containsEnchantment(CustomMendingEnchantment.getCustomMendingEnchantment())) {
            // Calculate repair cost based on damage
            int repairCost = calculateRepairCost(item);

            // Get player's total experience
            int totalExp = player.getTotalExperience();

            // Combine the player's total experience and experience from the event
            int combinedExp = totalExp + event.getAmount();

            // Check if event.getAmount() is enough for repairs
            if (event.getAmount() >= repairCost) {
                // Deduct the repair cost from the experience to be gained
                event.setAmount(event.getAmount() - repairCost);

                // Repair the item
                repairItem(item);
            }
            // Else, check if combined experience is enough for repairs
            else if (combinedExp >= repairCost) {
                // Set the player's total experience to the deduction of the repair cost from the combined experience
                player.setTotalExperience(combinedExp - repairCost);

                // Set the event amount to 0 since it has already been factored into the player's total experience
                event.setAmount(0);

                // Repair the item
                repairItem(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

I believe the code should fix the durability regen issue, but if you have any questions or if something is not working, please let me know!
